# ajax send info to python cgi automatically

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cgi

First of all, my server does not accept any additional frameworks but python, so I have to stick with it. I found a simple example om the internet. I have very few ajax knowledge and I need some help. Firstly, shoul I use python's cgi module and getvalue for "w" to transform this sample perl code to python? Secondly, where should I modify in the html part to reload the ajax part in a time interval instead of submitting it with a button?

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
var xmlHttpReq = false;
var self = this;
// Mozilla/Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
        updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
    }
}
self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
var form     = document.forms['f1'];
var word = form.word.value;
qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
<p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
<input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-    example.cgi")'></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Cgi part:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;

$query = new CGI;

$secretword = $query->param('w');
$remotehost = $query->remote_host();

print $query->header;
print "<p>The secret word is <b>$secretword</b> and your IP is <b>$remotehost</b>.</p>"
```

My Python interpretation of the preceding perl code(cgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi

myform = cgi.FieldStorage()
recieved = myform.getvalue('word')

print '<p> Hi mate, %s' % recieved
```

At least your answer helped me with the interval problem ;however, I still need to figure out the python part: should I get the value from the form using getvalue('w') or getvalue('word') in my python code because  I keep getting error when I run the code.

Comment: why use xmlhttprequest when you have jQuery

Comment: I have good knowledge about python, html and css but I really am a newbie at js and ajax. Thank you for the response but I do not have any clue about jquery, any help would be appreciated tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the second part only.

**The dirty way:**

Just before your `</script>` end tag:

```
var inv = setInterval(function () {
    xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.cgi");
}, 5000);

//if you ever want to stop
//call stopPolling()
function stopPolling() {
    clearInterval(inv);
}
```

This is dirty because it could lead to a memory leak scenario because the XMLHttpRequest object instantiation is inside the loop - you may end up creating lots of memory hogging objects should your server respond slower than your interval timer.

**A cleaner way**

- Use a library like jQuery
- If using a library is not feasible, first code a function for the Ajax object instantiation, with a variable cached properly so that you don't end up with a memory leak, and ensure you reuse the same object.
- Poll with a sensible interval time, taking into account your server's average response time and unexpected latencies.

Hope this helps.